# Buttons fall off & shirt opens during cloth simulation

Tags: import, cloth-simulation

I've loaded a figure and clothing from DAZ 3D via OBJ. I've assigned a cloth modifier to the shirt and set it to collide with the figure. The buttons are already part of the same object as the shirt. When the simulation starts, the buttons fall off the shirt and the shirt opens (please see attached images). I've tried to attach the buttons using intersect knife and then remove doubles, but apparently none of the button vertices are on a shirt edge. I've tried to separate a button to become its own object and used the CSG modifier to union it with the shirt. These do not work. As the 3rd image shows, the button is floating inside shirt mesh. So, there is a circular cross-section of the button that is in contact with the shirt mesh. Here are my questions:

1. Can I (semi-automatically?) add some vertices along this cross-section that are attached both to button edges and shirt edges? If not, what is the best (or easiest) way to attach the buttons to the shirt?
2. What is the best (or easiest) way to keep the shirt from opening during the simulation?

Thank you,
D. Vyd

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The best way to stick vertices together is to 'stitch' them. This technique is also used to create clothes in blender like Marvelous designer. Look it up on YouTube: 'Blender cloth like marvelous designer'.

Comment: I "vertex parented" buttons to my pillow and that works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make the buttons same object with the shirt, select all the buttons, then select the shirt, in that order, so the shirt is the active object, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.
The cloth simulator doesn't understand that those buttons are supposed to keep the shirt closed, you need to weld the open vertices where the shirt is open.
 In order to keep the visual of the shirt, you should do that in modeling, as you did for the collar for instance.

Comment: Thank you Georges. I've edited my question to clarify that the buttons are already part of the shirt. The problem seems to be that they do not share any edges or vertices. I separated one button into its own object to show the relationship in more detail and added a new image to my question.